# Boost beast compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast, beast

d:\boost\boost\beast\core\detail\ostream.hpp(263): error C2955: 'boost::beast::detail::ostream_helper': use of class template requires template argument list

When compiling example project:
http_server_small.cpp (from "beast")

boost\beast\core\detail\ostream.hpp:

```
template<class DynamicBuffer, class CharT, class Traits>
ostream_helper<DynamicBuffer, CharT, Traits, true>::
ostream_helper(
        ostream_helper&& other)
    : std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>(&osb_)
    , osb_(std::move(other.osb_))
{
}
```

Boost version 1.67.00, compiled under visual studio v171 (2017), x64

It looks like an error in boost/beast lib, but it's strange to see a compilation error in release version of the lib. (I'm not an author of the lib, I'm just trying to use it).

Maybe I'm missing some compilation options or flags?
Have any one figured out what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Checked the bugtracker already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it needs to be:

```
template<class DynamicBuffer, class CharT, class Traits>
ostream_helper<DynamicBuffer, CharT, Traits, true>::
ostream_helper(
    ostream_helper<DynamicBuffer, CharT, Traits, true>&& other)
: std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>(&osb_)
, osb_(std::move(other.osb_))
{
}
```

Cannot see how any compiler would allow it to be otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a configuration problem on your end because 1. Yes, it is valid C++, 2. I have no trouble compiling it using Visual Studio 2017 latest, in all configurations, and 3. the AppVeyor scripts regularly compile the library and examples, and have no trouble compiling it: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/vinniefalco/beast/history

Comment: The problem here may be that this member definition does not appear inside the template class definition.  In other questions I see people refer to 14.6.2.1 in C++11 standard.  That stipulates you can use the injected class name inside the template class definition.  But here the member function is defined outside, not inside.  In fact, in the same file, you can see the original definition above: ostream_helper(ostream_helper&& other); Yuri's compiler is fine with that, as that is inside the class definition.  I believe your compiler has gone beyond what is stipulated in the standard.

Comment: But this compiles correctly on many versions of gcc and many versions of clang: https://www.boost.org/development/tests/master/developer/beast.html

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure I'm right and even if I were, that doesn't mean that all those compilers are wrong, but I think it may explain why Yuri's compiler is behaving differently.